# How to tell auto-format in VS Code not to insert spaces after opening and before closing curly braces?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Whenever I use the auto-format shortcut (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>) in *Visual Studio Code* inside a file that contains this piece of code -

```
var keyframes = [
  {opacity: 0, transform: 'translate(0, 4em)'},
  {opacity: 1, transform: 'translate(0)'}
];
```

I get this -

```
var keyframes = [
  { opacity: 0, transform: 'translate(0, 4em)' },
  { opacity: 1, transform: 'translate(0)' }
];
```

I wonder if there's any way to tell the auto-format **not** to insert all the spaces?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, but the formatting options are currently not exposed to the user. It is high on our backlog.

Comment: Thanks Erich, if you could update the answer once it's supported, I will gladly accept it.

Comment: @JustinXL it seems to me the OP should accept the best correct answer -assuming there is a correct answer posted to the question. Liking the correct answer shouldn't be a requirement. ;-)

Comment: Do we have this option now? (I want to use it on React)

Comment: I was just wondering if this (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3039) is the correct ticket to observe the progress on the issue or if I would have to add a different one

Comment: There is now. Go through the answers

Answer (score 5):

If anyone is looking for that option in react it is:

```
"typescript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingJsxExpressionBraces": true
```

Then it will format this

```
<option key={org.id} value={org.id}>{org.displayName}</option>
```

like this:

```
<option key={ org.id } value={ org.id }>{ org.displayName }</option>
```

Comment: that's correct. I've got the same thing. really painful as the rest of the team is using intelliJ