# VS Code - Code Formatting space before curly braces

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

When I use autoformat function in VS Code editor it insert spaces before curly brackets like this:

From:

```
<Button onClick={this.callMyFunc.bind(this, screenSet.index)}>Add</Button>
```

To:

```
<Button onClick={this.callMyFunc.bind(this, screenSet.index) }>Add</Button>
```

From:

```
))}
```

To:

```
)) }
```

I can't find option what settings this... Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 20):

In 2020, the properties are called this way:

```
"javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingNonemptyBraces": false
"typescript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingNonemptyBraces": false
```

Comment: ...and since October 2020 there are [formatting options for empty curly braces as well](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_51#_empty-brace-formatting-option-for-javascript-and-typescript)

Answer (score 13):

Try putting this to your user settings:

```
"typescript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingNonemptyBrackets": false,
```

and maybe this too

```
"javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingNonemptyBrackets": false,
```

Comment: This setting doesn't work in JSX in .js files

Answer (score 9):

In preferences, you should set these to `true`

```
"javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingTemplateStringBraces": true,
"javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingJsxExpressionBraces": true
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems that despite those config settings, it is not yet [supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35565867/how-to-tell-auto-format-in-vs-code-not-to-insert-spaces-after-opening-and-before) in **VSCode**. :(

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `.prettierrc` file, you can set bracket spacing property to true

```json
module.exports = {
  bracketSpacing: true
};
```

Answer (score 1):

in `settings.json`

```
"javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingNonemptyBraces": false
```