# Visual Studio 2017 - Code Formatting - TypeScript - Space before and after curly braces

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

In our team we are using `TSLint` with `"jsx-curly-spacing": [ true, "always" ]`. Half our team uses VS Code and when they use `Code Formatting` they have this done automatically. However if i press 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to format the entire document the spacing is removed.

How I would like it to be:

```
<div className={ classes.root }>
```

How it turns out:

```
<div className={classes.root}>
```

I have looked at the settings but I can't find any for brackets.

[image]

I'm using the new `Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 15.5.3`.

VS Code has this automatically it seems and they can toggle it using these settings:

```
"typescript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingNonemptyBrackets": true,
```

[VS Code - Code Formatting space before curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37744231/vs-code-code-formatting-space-before-curly-braces)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a complete fix but it could be something. Since we are using `TSLint` and have `TypeScript Analyzer` installed I can right click the project or a single file/folder and then select `Fix TypeScript Analyzer Errors If Possible`. This solved my problem but it is an extra step.

[image]

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RichNewman.TypeScriptAnalyzer

I also added a feature request to Visual Studio for this.

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/32878903-code-formatting-typescript-and-javascript-spac